# Request entity error when docker deployed through vscode

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, flask

I am getting request entity 413 error when deploying a dockerized python flask application through vscode.
But when I run through docker desktop it works. But for other applications with same code, file, configuration it doesn't work even when executed through docker desktop.

Things that I have tried but didn't work

1. Setting app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] from None to very high value
2. Setting client_max_body_size
3. No problem with configurations since all applications are deployed on the same system yet one is working and others are not.
4. All packages versions are consistent
5. Tried using different browsers too
6. Consistent middle-ware balancer
7. No docker compose file is present.
8. All the containers are well within their threshold memory and CPU limit
9. No network issues.

Some observations:

1. Application 1 works when deployed through docker desktop but doesn't when deployed in vscode.
2. Two other applications don't work even through docker desktop.

How I am running through VSCode:

1. vscode is using docker extension to run the same docker container within vscode only
2. My launch.json is something like this
   { "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [ { "name": "Python: Flask", "type": "python", "request": "launch", "module": "flask", "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/code_mount", "env": { "FLASK_APP": "app_dev.py", "FLASK_DEBUG": "1", }, "args": [ "run", "--no-debugger", "--no-reload", "--port=5000" ], "jinja": true, "justMyCode": true, } ] }
3. I am selecting Run tab from Vscode toolbar and then start debugging

Comment: How are you deploying the flask application "through" vscode? Do you mean locally, like running `flask --app my_app run`? Whats the command you are using? Please give more details about how you are doing things.

Comment: Run-->Start Debugging Yes I am doing it locally